# Windows domain user logon without connection

Tags: windows, active-directory

How to let a user logon to a computer behind a domain without connection to Domain controller?
What i mean is that i need a notebook to work with its domain user also outside the domain network. Can i setup the notebook to store domain user authentication?

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations on giving us no information whatsoever, such as your server operating systems, your client operating systems, your domain functional level or the amount of time that this device will be off site.

The good news is that, yes, it's possible. By default the user device will cache the credentials of recently logged on users and allow them to log on even when there is no connection to the domain controller.

Start reading here to discover if this is a solution for your cirumstances: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994565(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Sorry if I forget to write "windows" ALSO in the message body, but i think the title and tags were quite explicative.

Comment: @Tobia That's a joke, right? You're aware that Windows as a product is now **26 years** old. I know you're surprised, but capabilities and methods have changed over time. So try again and try harder this time.